# Trying to update table with Python MySQL using user input

Tags: python, mysql

I was looking at questions with people have similar issues but I wasn't able to find a solution that worked.

Basically, I'm trying to create a program in `Python` that asks people for certain things. They then get put into the `MySQL` table. I have the `INSERT` part of it nailed and it works well. However, I'm struggling with the updating part of it (and the deleting). I've tried it a few different ways but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
    ename = input("What is the employees name?")
    enumber = int(input("What is the employees number?"))
    address = input("What is the employees address")
    dworked = int(input("How many days have they worked?"))
    holiday = input("Are they on holiday?")


mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO roster VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (ename, enumber, address, dworked, holiday))

mydb.commit()
```

That's the part that works fine.

I'm getting very confused with the `UPDATING` part because I'm not sure how to select a specific line of the table to update or how to update it once I've selected the specific line. I believe I may have to have an input that asks the user to select a certain line. Or is it possible to write code that recognizes a certain attribute in the input and realizes that's the line that has to be updated?.

```
update = input("Enter employee name")
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE roster SET update='%s' WHERE ename = '%s'")
    mydb.commit()
```

I'm probably just overthinking it at this stage but I'm getting really confused. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just have a [google about update queries](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=update+query&t=h_&ia=web). General syntax is `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = value WHERE columnname = value`

Comment: How are you passing values in with your update statement? What client are you using?

Comment: I'm using Pycharm and the mysql connector to connect to mysql database.

Comment: Where you execute your update query `mycursor.execute(“UPDATE...`, do you pass any values in there or the example code is exactly what you are doing?

Comment: The example code is what I'm doing. At the moment I'm getting errors because the 'update' variable isn't a column in my table so it can't update the details into the ename column

Comment: OK so are you trying to update the column named `ename` with the new input value? If so, the statement should be `UPDATE roster SET ename = %s WHERE ename = %s`. Also, there should be a second argument to your `execute` method call of a tuple containing `(new ename, old ename)`. See if this tutorial helps https://pynative.com/python-mysql-update-data/.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I've managed to get it to work without any errors but the update doesn't commit itself to the table for some reason. Is it possible it's because the insert and the update are together? Do they need to be in seperate definitions?

Answer (score 0):

```
empName = input("Enter employee name")
update = input("Enter new value")
sqlFormula = "UPDATE tableName SET columnName=%s WHERE empName = %s"
mycursor.execute(sqlFormula,(updateValue,empName))
mydb.commit()
#update = the value/name of the column you want to update
#empName = the name of the employee whose values you want to update
```

Hope it works, it worked for me:)

Comment: could you explain why it works? Code only answers are discouraged and considered as low quality